# 401 Not Authorized error in soapUI but web service works perfect in Postman

Tags: soap, postman, soapui, sap-erp

As the title states, when I send a request from soapUI to an SAP web service I am returned with an XML that contains an error message in it:

> 401 Nicht autorisiert (not authorized)

Since it is an SAP web service, I do have to input credentials when I create the new project, but those are the only credentials I have input before running the project.

With the same credentials, I am able to create a request and not receive an error message when I use the Postman interface.

Could this be an issue with the web service configuration, or is this an authorization issue with soapUI?

Links to images:

- SoapUI (broken link):
  [image]
- Postman:
  [image]

Comment: It sounds like you are using SoapUI wrong. What does the request look like in Postman, and what does it look like in SoapUI? Include all headers!

Comment: @SiKing thank you for your help. I have posted the image links. Please let me know if you need more information.

Comment: Can you convert the screenshots of text back to plain text, and add that to the question here.

Answer (score 3):

From your images it looks like the `Authorization: Basic...` header is not being sent as part of your HTTP request out of soapUI and I assume your service doesn't challenge for the credentials in a way that soapUI understands.

One way around this is to click the `Authenticate pre-emptively` radio button on the basic authorization dialog box. This will construct and send the header the same way as Postman.